# How to best practice restoring a wallet in bitcoin core

Tags: bitcoin-core, security, private-key, wallet-recovery, coldcard

I have a test wallet in bitcoin core that I want to play around with and get comfortable with before I move my btc from blockstream green wallet. I primarily use that wallet because so far it has been easy to understand. So I have created this core wallet, sent $1 worth of btc to it, so not worried if I mess it up. I have backed up the wallet.dat file, backed up my private key and backed up my encyrpted passphrase all physically.

How would I go about deleting the wallet so I could practice restoring it? When you restore a wallet do your addresses automatically show up, or do you also need to import your private keys for each address in this case I have one test address.

I ordered a coldcard and want to use it with bitcoin core. Looks like I can here
https://github.com/Coldcard/firmware/blob/master/docs/bitcoin-core-usage.md for storage and need to do something called HWI for sending. I think I am reading this correctly.

Is this a good practice for security, I was looking at https://yeticold.com/ seemed interesting but it failed to restore my wallet, but it integrates with bitcoin core. I think it's just still very new so not good for storing anything real at the moment, I posted a issue on github with no response.

Apologies for jumping from one thing to another

To Summarize

A. what is the best practice for getting my feet wet with bitcoin core, ideally practicing restoring a wallet and private keys.

B. Is coldcard with bitcoin core very secure?

C. What's the deal with yeticold.com

and finally, is there a good practice for generating my encryption password for bitcoin wallets, is this what people generally call a seed phrase in most wallets, what is a seed phrase in other wallets vs cores passphrase.

Thanks ahead of time. Im new to bitcoin security so hopefully I am making sense. I don't mind spending the time to learn and practice things slowly to get this right, so fine with good resources to read.